# What is the probability of getting a 3-of-a-kind in a 7 card poker hand?

Tags: probability, card-games

Obviously, the denominator in the probability formula is $\binom{52}{7}$. For the numerator I was thinking it would be $\binom{13}{1}\binom{4}{3}\binom{48}{4}$, but this gives a probability of about 7.56%, whether wiki says it should be around [4.83%](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poker_probability). What's the correct approach?

Comment: Please edit your post and your and add your question to it.

Comment: I think the question is fairly clear.

Comment: Hint: You have to avoid hands such as a full house (and other higher hands).

Comment: I'm going with @paw88789 here. However, even including all possible higher hands, this is still incorrect, because you're counting hands twice which have three of a kind two times.

Comment: Do you mean 3 of a kind or better, or exactly one 3 of a kind in a hand? With 7 cards you could have two sets of triplets.

Comment: @copper.hat Going to the linked page (Wikipedia), you take the best five-card hand you can get from the seven cards. So double three-of-a-kind is not a thing. That hand would be a full house. (And a full house would not be counted in the probability for three-of-a-kind.) You need three of a kind; and four other cards of four different ranks; and no (five-card) straight and no (five-card) flush.

Comment: @paw88789 Thanks, so presumably something like $1,2,2,2,3,3,3$ would be a 3 of a kind. I imagine working this out by hand would be messy.

Comment: @copper.hat $1,2,2,2,3,3,3$ would be a full house (you can use your best five-card hand).

Comment: @paw88789 Of course, thanks. Dire need of caffeine.